# System fail to sleep

Tags: suspend, dell, power-management

My Dell XPS 9550 fails to sleep.

I can see errors like these in logs after a failed sleep attempt

```
dpm_run_callback() returns -5
brcmfmac 0000:02:00.0 PM: failed to suspend async: error -5
brcmfmac 0000:02:00.0: brcmf_pcie_pm_enter_D3: Timeout on response for entering D3 substate
ieee80211 phy0: brcmf_inetaddr_changed: fail to get arp ip table err:-52
```

I am on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS and `uname -a` produces this

```
5.15.0-48-generic #54-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 26 13:26:29 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I am not sure are these the relevant errors or not and there does not seem to be much information about these online. Anyone can help?

Thank You!